# Automatically use virtualenv when calling a python script in Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner and I can't find a concrete answer on how to do what I'm trying to accomplish:

Basically I call my script "traffic.py" from a Java app, so I need my script to automatically use the virtualenv I created for it. I read that if you put your script in the ./bin/ folder from your virtualenv, it automatically uses its interpreter. This works on Ubuntu, but whenever I try the same thing on Windows, I get an error message telling me "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psutil'", indicating that the virtualenv has not been activated.

I'm sure the answer is really simple, and greatly appreciate you taking your time to read my post!

Answer (score 0):

You can call the python script with PYTHONHOME set to the virtualenv directory.

https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHOME

Comment: I can't find any way to correctly setting it in my file directly. and setting PYTHONHOME for my OS would only temporarily solve my problem. Mind telling me how to set it?

Comment: How exactly are you calling the script from Java?